# Is there a way using Tkinter to open a file dialog and return a file path like ~/filefolder/*.csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to use tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames in Python to allow a user to either select existing file, or to be able to go to a folder and type *.csv and press open.

```
from tkinter import *
...
selectedfiles = askopenfilename()
```

Selecting existing files is fine, however I am unable to allow the user to type *.csv to return to the program a string of the path to the folder plus their selection (something like "~/folder/*.csv").  Doing this just filters the files shown in the open file dialog.

Is there any way, either using askopenfilename() or other to accomplish this?

Comment: No, but you can use askopendirectory() to let the user select a folder and then just get all the .csv files from this folder. This would be two different dialogs, however. The user has to have the choice of selecting one file or all files in a given folder.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can pass `multiple=True` to allow then to select multiple files, but they can't literally type a wild card.